# How multiple images are stitched

Tags: image-stitching

I was trying to learn the theory behind image stitching and found articles on how to stitch only two images. I read many papers on stitching such as Lowe who has represented a great paper on image stitching. But one thing is missing always, how are multiple images matched? Is it 1st image with all other images, stitch them, then result of that with remaining set of images? If someone could clear out my doubt it would be great

Answer (score 3):

From what I have learnt working with opencv, this is what I have gathered their approach is:

The **matching** and **stitching** are done in two different steps -

**Matching**

1. Get each image and compare with the rest one by one. The comparison here is done by looking at the similarity in feature points between the two images.
2. Rank the similarity between the images
3. Pairs with low similarity will be discarded, pairs with high enough similarity will be kept.

**Stitching**

1. The first image from the panorama is placed
2. The next image is placed in relation to the first image depending on
   the homography between the two. A homography is simply a 3x3 matrix
   describing how to move from one image to the next.
3. Another image is placed in relation to either the first image if
   there are more matches regarding image one or the second image if
   there aren't.
4. This process is repeated until there are no more matches for the
   images left in the panorama.

---

There are some other steps in between matching and stitching, which include improving the homography using bundle estimation, finding where the images join - which is known as seam estimation - as well as some warping procedures. However I hope this enough info to answer the question you asked.